# Orbital height without the gravitational constant and the mass of either object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, satellites

Is it possible to calculate the orbital height of an object using only the orbital period T = 93min, radius of the Earth R = 6378km and the gravitational acceleration at the surface of the Earth g = 9,8m/s^2? Until now I've used the equation:

Fc = Fg

mv^2/r = GmM/r^2

v^2 = GM/r

4pi^2r^2/T^2 = GM/r

r^3 = GMT^2/4pi^2

r - distance between the centres of mass of the two objects, G - gravitational constant, M - mass of the Earth, T - orbital period.

But without knowing the gravitational constant or the mass of the Earth I can't seem to calculate this. I believe I have to somehow use the gravitational acceleration, but it only applies to the surface and is very different at the altitude of the satelite. How would I be able to calculate this?

Comment: with the answer of Neil I got the ISS hight 419 km , which is correct, I wonder how you solved this problem with the answer of mike , because g(r) is unknown?

Comment: @Eli Could you please tell me how you solved it, I tried asking Neil, but he wasn't of much help

Comment: @Eli I can't use M or G.

Comment: $R+h=\left( \dfrac{GMT^{2}}{4\, \pi^2}\right) ^{\dfrac{1}{3}}.=\left( \dfrac{gT^2R^{2}}{4\,\pi^2 }\right) ^{\dfrac{1}{3}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need $G$. Just use proportionality: The gravitational acceleration at height $r$ is related to the $g$ at the surface $R_{\rm earth}$ by
$$
g(r) = g_{\rm surface} \frac{R_{\rm earth}^2}{r^2}
$$

Comment: $r\mapsto R_e+h$

Comment: @mike stone g(r) is unknown, so how you solve your equation for h ?

Comment: @Eli Fg = g(r)*m, and you know everything except for m and r, but m cancels out and r is the only unknown, so the final equation is r = cube root(gR^2T^2/4pi^2) where g is the gravitational acceleration on the surface (9,8m/s^2), R is the radius of Earth (6378000m) and T is the orbital period (5880s)

Comment: @mike stone Thank you very much, this has worked, but could you explain why the relationship actually works?

Comment: It is just propertionality from Newton's inverse square law: $g_{\rm gravity}=GM/r^2$. Take ratios and the $GM$ factor cancels.

Comment: @mikestone I'm sorry, I still don't quite understand where the radius of the earth came from. Could you please show me how you derived the formula?

Comment: Gravitational acceleration at earth;'s surface $g_{\rm surface}= GM_{\rm earth} /R_{\rm earth}^2$. Gravitational acceleration at $r= R_{\rm earth}+h$ is $g(r)= GM_{\rm earth}/r^2$. Divide the second by the first to get $g(r)= g_{\rm surface} R_{\rm earth}^2/r^2$.

Answer (score 1):

First get $\omega$ from, $\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T}$, then equate it with,

$\omega^2(h+r)=\frac{GM}{(h+r)^2}\Rightarrow (h+r)^3=\frac{GM}{\omega^2}$

This is kepler's third law, where $h$ is height of ISS from earth's surface, $r$ is radius of earth, $M$ is mass of earth.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little, I am still a student and don't have a very deep understanding of physics. What would be the final equation for the orbital height? Until now I was using that the centrifugal and gravitational force are equal but act in opposite directions, so I can set them equal to one another and solve for r, which gave me: r^3 = G*M*T^2/4*pi^2.

Comment: @JanHrubec Use $r+h$ instead of $r$, then minus $r$ from it to get $h$. .

Comment: Ok, but I still don't know the value of G or M so I can't calculate it

Comment: @JanHrubec Okay, $GM=gr^2$. Now either put it wherever it needs or reformulate above equation by taking first order expansion as $r>>h$. Therefore, $1+\frac{3h}{r}=\frac{1}{\omega^2r}$ or $h=\frac{1}{3\omega^2}-\frac{r}{3}$.

Comment: Amazing, could I just ask, is GM=gr^2 based in any equation or is there any way I could prove it?

Comment: @JanHrubec It is acceleration due to gravity, law of gravitation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140746/discussion-between-jan-hrubec-and-neil-libertine).